# gitolite can't clone repository

Tags: server, ssh, git

I have a small server with a friend together and we've install gitolite on it. However every time we try to clone the gitolite-admin repository we got only the following error message.

```
Klone nach 'gitolite-admin' ...

Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

and the repository exists.

I'm sure we've set the right public key for the git user, but the problem is still alive.

We use Ubuntu 14.04 and we've install gitolite over the Ubuntu repositories.